# flex datagrid columns drag

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a data grid where users can drag columns and reposition them.
But there is a strange requirement that some columns should not be draged to the left of some other column.

eg, assume the columns are :  name, price , start date, end date,

The end date should not be dragged and placed before the start date.
i.e. The user can have

- start date, price , name , end date.
- name, start date, price , end date.

But at no point can end date appear before start date.

**Is there a way to do this flex?
Is there a way to know where the user is trying to drop the column and show error message ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution involves a work around.

- First use a Advanced data grid instead of a Data grid.
- Then create a column Group and add Start Date and End Date columns to it.
- Then set childrenDragEnabled="false" in the column group.
- Thats the work around. Sample code below.

Solution (notice `childrenDragEnabled="false"`):

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup childrenDragEnabled="false">
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="startDate" />
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="endDate" />
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the [headerShift](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event%3aheaderShift) event, check the new index against the indexes of the ones its not allowed to be before, and move it back yourself.

Comment: Thank you, This event seems to be fired after the columns are set for  a swap. i.e. grid.columns[oldIndex] is not the column being moved, but the column on which it is being dropped. Also, how can we stop this event from completing the swap of columns.  -- This is not clear yet, I need to explore. Please let me know if you can shed some light on it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a protected method that corresponds to the event, and the event itself seems to be dispatched after the event. You'll need to monkey patch the DG code to make it work I suspect, there's no good way external to the DG that I can see of stopping the shift.

Comment: :( , I will probably try to swap-back the columns in the event instead of blocking it. Hopefully that should be a good enough work around. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Gregor, I tried to manually swap the columns in the event but it did not work so i was forced with a work around, solution is attached.